# R check consistency of separated timeseries-table

Tags: r

I have a timeseries-table like this, which goes up to 2000 31 12 23 (12/31/2000 23:00):

[image: timeseries-format]

I'd like to add temparature values from several weatherstations to it. The problem is, that obviously the different timeseries dont't match by count of rows, so there must be gaps.

How can I check up on these dataframes if they consequently follow the pattern of 0-24 hours, 1-12 months and get information of where these gaps are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you answer and sorry for my late reply.
Couldn't make it without your helpful hints though I now managed to merge all my timeseries on a slightly different way:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC') #setting system time to UTC for not having DST-gaps

# creating empty hourly timeseries for following join
start = strptime("1962010100", format="%Y%m%d%H")
end = strptime("2000123123", format= "%Y%m%d%H")
series62_00 <- data.frame(
MESS_DATUM=seq(start, end, by="hour",tz ='UTC'), t = NA)

# joining all the temperatureseries with same timespan using "plyr"-package
library("plyr")
t_allstations <- list(series62_00,t282,t867,t1270,t2261,t2503
,t2597,t3668,t3946,t4752,t5397,t5419,t5705)
t_omain_DWD <- join_all(t_allstations, by = "MESS_DATUM", type = "left")
```

Using `join_all` with `type = "left"` makes sure, that the column "Date" is not changed and missing temperature values are filled in as `NA's`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in the format of the link then you can probably convert it to a POSIXct object by doing the following (assuming your data frame is called data):

```
data = as.data.frame(list(YY = rep("1962",10),
                      MM = rep("01",10),
                      DD = rep("01",10),
                      HH = c("00","01","02","03","04",
                             "05","06","07","08","09")))

date = paste(data$YY,data$MM,data$DD,sep="-")

data$dateTime = as.POSIXct(paste(date,data$HH,sep=" "),format="%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

That should put your data into a POSIXct format. If your temperature dataset also has a column called "dateTime" and it's a POSIXct object you should be able to use the merge function and it will combine the two data frames

```
temp = as.data.frame(list(YY = rep("1962",10),
                      MM = rep("01",10),
                      DD = rep("01",10),
                      HH = c("00","01","02","03","04",
                             "05","06","07","08","09")))

date1 = paste(temp$YY,temp$MM,temp$DD,sep="-")

temp$dateTime = as.POSIXct(paste(date1,temp$HH,sep=" "),format="%Y-%m-%d %H")

temp$temp = round(rnorm(10,0,5),1)
temp = temp[,c("dateTime","temp")]

#let's say your temperature dataset is missing an entry for a certain timestamp
temp = temp[-3,]

# this data frame won't have an entry for 02:00:00
data1 = merge(data,temp)
data1

# if you want to look at time differences you can try something like this
diff(data1$dateTime)

# this one will fill in the temp value as NA at 02:00:00
data2 = merge(data,temp,all.x = T)
data2

diff(data2$dateTime)
```

I hope that helps, I often use the merge function when I'm trying to match up timestamps from ecological datasets